# Obtener Datos especificos desde una Variable mediante un $_Request

Tags: php

Quisiera saber con que método puedo separar contenido de un conjunto de datos recibidos mediante un request.

Los datos recibidos llegan en la siguiente forma:

```
    <MPFIN>
 <IDTRX>1344</IDTRX> - Id Transacción del comercio informado.

<CODRET>0000</CODRET> - Código retorno que indica el estado final de la transacción.

<DESCODRET>Transacción exitosa</DESCODRET> - Descripción del estado final de la
transacción.

   </MPFIN>
```

¿Cómo hago para validar el codigo de la transacción? es decir solo el campo `<CODRET>0000</CODRET>`

Lo que quiero es comparar mediante un `if` que dependiendo del número que reciba en éste campo las acciones a realizar (si recibo `0000` hago algo y si recibo `0001` hacer otra cosa).

Tengan en cuenta que la variable o el campo `MPFIN` me la envian desde un servidor externo mediante un `$_POST[]`, es de tipo String y uso un `$_REQUEST` para obtener los datos.

No se cómo separar cada campo de esta variable que recibo y obtener el campo que quiero evaular.

¿Existe alguna función o método para hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: Es extraño que te lo manden así. ¿Si usas `$_POST["CODRET"];` o `$_REQUEST["CODRET"];` no obtienes el valor?

Comment: no , no recibo nada.. si hago un var_dump($_REQUEST["MPFIN"])  solo obtengo algo tipo  "     13440000Transaccion exitosa   "

Comment: ¿Pero te envían un XML completo o es solamente lo que muestras en la pregunta?

Comment: realmente no se si es un XML completo, pero lo que me llega son solo esos valores ( los que muestro en la pregunta ) .. de igual forma no se como imprimir si es de tipo xml y como puedo visualizar realmente lo que me llega ya que con var_dump solo me imprime lo que te dije anteriormente

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas `var_dump($_REQUEST);`  o `var_dump($POST);` qué muestra ?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que es un xml, podrías utilizar la clase `simpleXML` de php:  http://php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-basic.php